# How to display 3 arrays using the format: element + element = element in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, display

Like the title suggests, I am trying to display elements from multiple arrays in the format above. I needed to create 3 arrays with a length of 25. The first is filled using the loop counter, the second is the loop counter squared and the 3rd array is filled with the sum of array 1 and 2. I have all three arrays filled but when I compile and run it, it seems to output what I want but loops way more times then I need it to.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    
    double[] array1 = new double[25];
    double[] array2 = new double[25];
    double[] array3 = new double[25];
    
    
    for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        array1[i] = i + 1.0;
        for (int j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
            array2[j] = array1[i] * array1[i];
            for (int k = 0; k < array3.length; k++) {
                array3[k] = array1[i] + array2[j];
                System.out.println(array1[i] + " + " + array2[j] + " + " + " = " + array3[k] + " ");
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is because you are trying to loop for each element of each array. That is why instead of getting the output just 25 times. You're getting it 25*25*25 times

Answer (score 2):

You made too many for you just need one

```
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        
        double[] array1 = new double[25];
        double[] array2 = new double[25];
        double[] array3 = new double[25];
        
        
        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
            array1[i] = i + 1.0;
            array2[i] = array1[i] * array1[i];
            array3[i] = array1[i] + array2[i];
            System.out.println(array1[i] + " + " + array2[i] + " + " + " = " + array3[i] + " ");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Oh my goodness... I can't believe it was that simple. I knew it seemed odd iterating through multiple for loops, as they built off each other... live and learn I guess. I really appreciate it. This will help with my project. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You have overcomplicated the problem, you're repeating each squaring 25 times, and each addition 625 times, you need only one loop. That can be seen by looking at each arrays at the end, their filled with the last iteration, everywhere

```
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 20.0, 21.0, 22.0, 23.0, 24.0, 25.0]
[625.0, 625.0, 625.0, 625.0, 625.0, 625.0, 625.0, 625.0, 625.0, 625.0, 625.0, 625.0, 625.0, 625.0, 625.0, 625.0, 625.0, 625.0, 625.0, 625.0, 625.0, 625.0, 625.0, 625.0, 625.0]
[650.0, 650.0, 650.0, 650.0, 650.0, 650.0, 650.0, 650.0, 650.0, 650.0, 650.0, 650.0, 650.0, 650.0, 650.0, 650.0, 650.0, 650.0, 650.0, 650.0, 650.0, 650.0, 650.0, 650.0, 650.0]
```

One loop is enough, one index is enough:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    array1[i] = i + 1.0;
    array2[i] = array1[i] * array1[i];
    array3[i] = array1[i] + array2[i];
    System.out.println(array1[i] + " + " + array2[i] + " = " + array3[i]);
}
```

Note that if you don't need the values after the loop, don't store them

```
for (int i = 1; i < array1.length + 1; i++) {
    System.out.println(i + " + " + (i * i) + " = " + (i + i * i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need three nested loops, just a single loop over the shared length:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    array1[i] = i + 1.0;
    array2[j] = array1[i] * array1[i];
    array3[k] = array1[i] + array2[j];
    System.out.println(array1[i] + " + " + array2[j] + " + " + " = " + array3[k] + " ");
}
```